# Wire two bean in spring 4

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean named "basic" which I want to wire into another bean named callingApp, how do i do that?

1st bean

```
@Bean
public Phone basic() {
    Phone phone = new BasicPhone();
    return phone;

}
```

2nd bean

```
 @Bean
public CallingApp callingApp() {



    return new CallingApp( i want to inject bean of BasicPhone here);
}
```

Comment: Once you call "new" to create a bean it's no longer under Spring factory control.  You either wire them in Spring or do it yourself.

Comment: Is this in a @Configuration class?  If so, just call `basic()`: `new CallingApp(basic());`

Comment: @duffymo, that is not correct. You can instantiate beans programatically and add them to the spring context by adding '@Bean'.

Comment: Beans instantiated with "new" aren't wired by Spring in my experience.  Try it and confirm.

Comment: @duffymo first result in google: http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2014/10/spring-configuration-and-injecting-bean.html. In case you down-voted the question, please undo it.

Comment: Nope try it out with your "new" bean.  It is not under the control of the Spring bean factory.

Comment: @duffymo, Please check the official documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html. To make it more easier, search the page for `return new MyBean();`

Comment: Please run code and prove that can use Spring to inject a dependency into a bean that you've instantiated by calling new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the methods you presented are placed inside a java class annotated with `@Configuration` you should just do the following:

```
@Bean
public CallingApp callingApp(Phone phone) {
    return new CallingApp(phone);
}
```

Spring will autowire the dependency `Phone phone` by type. In case you have multiple beans of this type, you should use `@Qualifier("basic")`, because when you instantiate a bean by annotating a method with `@Bean`, the name of the bean will be set to the method name by default.

```
@Bean
public CallingApp callingApp(@Qualifier("basic") Phone phone) {
    return new CallingApp(phone);
}
```

In case you want to change the name of the bean of type Phone, you can also use `@Qualifier` as follows:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("basicPhone")
public Phone basic() {
    Phone phone = new BasicPhone();
    return phone;

}
```

**EDIT**

An easy example on how to achieve what you want is the following [blog post](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2014/10/spring-configuration-and-injecting-bean.html)